# Printing out std::string

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream, cout

In the sample code below

```
    std::string result = exec( "dir" ) ;
    cout<<result;
```

I get the following error

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type 'class std::basic_string

I suspect there is a special method to print out an `std::string`.

Please help me debug this.

Also, I have included **iostream.h**, **fstream.h** and **stream** header files.

Comment: You should have included `<iostream>` and `<fstream>` without `h`. If that doesn't help, show more code. You do have `using namespace std`?

Comment: Have you included `#include <string>`?

Comment: @MrLister: Thanks. you solved it. Please post it as an answer so that others make use of it... thanks.

Comment: Thanks all of you. @MrLister exactly pointed out the mistake. Waiting for him to add an answer so that I change the status of this question.

Comment: In future, please provide the shortest complete program you can create that demonstrates the problem. You can't expect people to debug an entire program from only two lines of code, especially when those two lines don't include the bug. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Actually, while posting the question I just suspected the error in these two lines. I didn't know that the error was somewhere else when I was posting the question.

Comment: And that, in a nutshell, is why I ask you in future questions to include a complete program; only then are you guaranteed to include the problematic parts.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Thanks, I'll surely take care next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question **on behalf of @MrLister** since he was inactive.

I should have included `<iostream>` and `<fstream>` without `.h`. Also `using namespace std;` should have been typed after that.

Ex:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib>

using namespace std;
```

**Many many thanks to @MrLister.**

And **thanks to @dasblinkenlight.** His answer enhanced a little bit.

Comment: OK. You can mark this as correct, since if I'd answer now, it'd look just like a copy of yours. By the way, you don't actually _need_ `using namespace std;` as long as you type `std::` in front of everything.

Comment: no. I just checked... `using namespace std;` was needed. Without it, I got the same error.

Comment: That's odd, that doesn't happen here. There must be more to your program than meets the eye.

Comment: Then I suspect you have something else named `cout` in another part of your program. Not that that isn't OK, mind you, but that's where this particular error comes from.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you need to qualify `cout` with `std::`

```
    std::cout << result;
```

or add `using namespace::std` to the top of your cpp file.

Comment: @KerrekSB I would agree if we were talking about adding `using namespace::std` in the header: that's a big "no-no". However, I think that in implementation file it is very much OK.

Comment: Well, you know kids these days. They hear one thing somewhere and then use it in other places "because someone on StackOverflow said to". Mind you, I'm not saying it's wrong. Just a bit iffy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `<string>`

Comment: you should have mentioned that in the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

cout is defined in `<iostream>`. Getting the `<<` syntax to work with `std::string`s requires `<sstream>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string result = "something";
std::cout << result << " and something else";
```